# Parse string by semicolon using parsec

Tags: haskell, parsec

This is one of my task. Parser getList suppose to work next way

```
GHCi> parseTest getList "1;234;56"
["1","234","56"]
GHCi> parseTest getList "1;234;56;"
parse error at (line 1, column 10):
unexpected end of input
expecting digit
GHCi> parseTest getList "1;;234;56"
parse error at (line 1, column 3):
unexpected ";"
expecting digit
```

My solution `` getList = many digit `sepBy1` char ';' `` is working like this

```
*Main> test1
["1","234","56"]
*Main> test2
["1","234","56",""]
*Main> test3
["1","","234","56"]
```

It's not correct, I can't figure out how to deal with double-quoted cases.

Comment: Just `filter` empty strings out?

Comment: It supposed to be parser solution only and should works exactly as in first box.

Comment: `many digit \`sepBy\` (many1 $ char ';')` then?

Comment: Nope, it's not giving errors in second and third cases.

Comment: I don't get it. You need to parse double `;` or you need to error out on them?

Comment: `parseTest getList "1;;234;56"
parse error at (line 1, column 3):
unexpected ";"
expecting digit` - this is correct answer, but your variant gives `["1","234","56"]` I need error them out, and input should not end on `;` it's also error

Comment: side note - if you are parsing csv - be aware of [cassava](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cassava)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem what `many digit` it's parser which accepts zero or more digits. You should use, for example, `many1 digit`. So all together:

```
getList = many1 digit `sepBy` char ';'
```

Comment: Thanks, you're savior:)

Answer (score 1):

Using `megaparsec` (which I recommend over `parsec`):

```
getList = some digitChar `sepBy1` char ';'
```

This means "at least one digit, at least one time, separated by semicolons". Note that I'm using `some` where your attempt used `many`.

```
ghci> parse getList "" "123;456"
Right ["123", "456"]
ghci> parse getList "" "123;;456"
Left (ParseError {errorPos = SourcePos {sourceName = "", sourceLine = Pos 1, sourceColumn = Pos 5} :| [], errorUnexpected = fromList [Tokens (';' :| "")], errorExpected = fromList [Label ('d' :| "igit")], errorCustom = fromList []})
```

Comment: Thanks for solution, but this is for educational purposes, so I have to use parsec

Comment: I'm sure you're capable of figuring out how to translate it into Parsec. The only real difference is that Parsec spells `digitChar` as `digit`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
getList = do
    many1 digit
    many $ do
       char ';'
       many1 digit
```

Comment: Last tests are correct, but first is wrong `["234", "56"]`

Comment: Well, you need to think a bit too. The first number **is** parsed, you just need to find out how to pull it out of this do-block.

Comment: If I have enough knoweledge I would do exactly as you said and more I don't ask anything here either. Anyway thanks.